# How to put DDS Textures on the OBJ in WPF (C#)

Tags: c#, wpf, 3d, windows, helix-3d-toolkit

All that I'm trying to do is to put the DDS on the OBJ captured by the Kinect v2.

I've retrieved the OBJ from Kinect as well as created the DDS texture but unable to put it on the OBJ.

Since I'm new to this ecosystem of Windows and 3D modelling. I'm unable to find any way to get this thing done. Any help would be very much appreciated.

The application is a Windows App using Windows 8.1 SDK and I'm using Helix-Toolkit to load OBJ.

Answer (score 0):

hy, 
its little bit late, but may be it will help,
with the .obj file there is a file with .mtl extension  in this file you fill find the reference to materials used in .obj file and eventually the reference to textures files .

Answer (score 0):

You will also need a handler for dds files. `System.Drawing.Design`, can take of this for you.